# How to Remove Facebook Comments Plugin From A Blogger Blog

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, blogger

I have a blogger blog

I want to completely remove Facebook Comments Widget/Plugin and replace it with Disqus since I know that viewers would prefer Disqus more than Facebook plugin.

I tried a lot of times to remove facebook plugin but even if I remove it some or other problems keep rising. Like I won't be able to add Disqus comments or neither Google comments work.

The theme I am using is a 3rd party designed theme and the developer and his website is nowhere to be found anymore. His website was closed and he can't be contacted from anywhere else.

Though I have modified a lot of parts, here is the theme of my blog:

pastebin.com/EJieAgfe

The above theme is directly downloaded from my blog. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click anywhere inside your code area, press **CTRL + F**, search for `<body>` and remove the next block of code

```
<div id='fb-root'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fb_load(){var d=document.createElement(&quot;script&quot;);d.src=&quot;//cdn.rawgit.com/tutorialku/usagilabs/master/fb_us.js&quot;,document.body.appendChild(d)}window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener(&quot;load&quot;,fb_load,!1):window.attachEvent?window.attachEvent(&quot;onload&quot;,fb_load):window.onload=fb_load;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bassam, and can you tell me how to add Disqus manually in template, I don't think the method given by Disqus will work since the template is made so that none of the widgets in homepage will load in any other pages than homepage.

Comment: Follow [link1](https://so-how-do-i.blogspot.com.au/2017/03/add-disqus-comments-to-my-blog.html) or [link2](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/888340-manually-adding-a-disqus-gadget-to-blogger)

Comment: Nope not working, both of them :(. I tried putting it next to Blog1 widget inside the same section. But both of them are not working.

Comment: Be sure to write the right `disqus_shortname` like this `var disqus_shortname = &#39;https-yourblogname-blogspot-com&#39;;`